# how to pass multiple ids as an array in form collection_select rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

`project` has one_to_many association with `stages` and `financial`
`stage` has one_to_many association with `task`
`task` has one_to_many association with `sub_task`.

In **Financial#form** view i am trying to pass `id` to **collection_select** as an array of combined ids like (eg:-id of stage, id of parent stage . id of task, id of stage.id of task. id of sub_task . id of sub_task) 

Also drop-down first accesses all stages then task in current scenario is how can i turn drop-down like first stages then their corresponding all task followed by all sub_tasks?

[image]

**How can code identify which value is from which table, because drop-down comes from multiple table based on reference**

form.html.erb (Finacial)

```
<div class="field column large-8">
  <br>
  <%= form.label :acitivity_Select %>
  <%= form.collection_select :cost_head, @project.stages.all+ @project.tasks.all+ @project.sub_tasks.all, :id, :task_name, prompt: true %>
</div>
```

project.rb

```
  has_many :stages
  has_many :tasks, through: :stages
  has_many :sub_tasks, through: :tasks
```

Comment: Why do you want to combine all of them under same collection_select

Comment: @Nithin i am trying to store parent child id together, so that in financial i can identify which stage,task or sub_task is linked with particular financial?

Comment: @Nithin  there can be some ```tasks``` from stage, task, and sub_task table linked to some financial not all tasks will be linked to financial, also there are some financial which will not be linked to any ```tasks``` from stage, task and sub_task table.

Comment: Do you want stages and tasks to be selectable or should a user only be able to select a sub-task (and stages and tasks are merely grouping elements)?

Comment: @ClemensKofler , drop-down is created based taking task_name column from stage, task, and sub_task table, based on project_id. if i pass only id how i code will be able to identify this data is from which table. since primary key counter is similar to each table i.e (1...n)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here's how I'd go about solving this:

From a data perspective, there's no need to fetch and render the stages and tasks at all, because you can access that data via the sub tasks. So if you render the select accordingly and store the sub task's ID in the database, you'll be able to access the task and stage from it:

```html
<%= form.collection_select :cost_head, @project.sub_tasks, :id, :task_name, prompt: true %>
```

Anywhere else:

```rb
financial.cost_head.task # => the task
financial.cost_head.task.stage # => the stage
```

If you want to include IDs in the select for easier selection, you can write your own `label_method`, e.g. like so:

In the SubTask model:

```rb
def full_task_name
  "#{task.stage.id}.#{task.id}.#{id} #{task_name}"
end
```

And then in the form:

```html
<%= form.collection_select :cost_head, @project.sub_tasks, :id, :full_task_name, prompt: true %>
```

If the sorting is off, you might need to do something like this:

In the controller:

```rb
@cost_heads = @project.sub_tasks.includes(task: :stage).order("stages.id ASC, tasks.id ASC, sub_tasks.id ASC")
```

In the form:

```html
<%= form.collection_select :cost_head, @cost_heads, :id, :full_task_name, prompt: true %>
```